# Switch to ORMLite and rewrite backend, or migrate hibernate backend code to tomcat server? Porting to android

Tags: java, android, hibernate, tomcat, ormlite

I'm working on an Android app right now that needs to communicate with a MySQL server. For obvious reasons I would like to use an ORM.  My problem is that I wrote and tested the backend for the system on my desktop, and this being my first time with Android and backend systems in general, wrote it all to use Hibernate. When I went to load my application onto a phone, I had a great deal of trouble with Hibernate; it is not meant for mobile development.

The way I see it I have two ways out of this hole. Option one: I modify my codebase to use ORMLite (a light ORM that suits Android well). After a cursory glance at the documentation, I see that many of the Hibernate's features that *are* supported in ORMLite require complete rewrites; there would be very little reusable code. Even the POJOs would need to be rewritten. While this seems like a daunting task, if it is determined that it is the best course of action, I will happily pursue it.

My second option is to migrate my Hibernate code to a Tomcat server (or something of the sort), so that my application can still have all the functionality it has now on my desktop, but outsource the processing. I know very little about Tomcat or JSF applications in general, however again if need be, I will happily pursue this option. I don't even know if this option is feasible! Again, I just need guidance.

So my question is, of the two methods, which would be

1. The most efficient (in terms of my application)
2. The best practice (option two may be a major no-no, I'm just not sure)
3. The smallest headache (I think a headache of some sort is unavoidable at this point)

Thanks in advance for your help!

edit: In response to a comment below, I am not deadset on Tomcat as a J2EE provider. I listed it simply because I knew what it was. Moreover I need to know whether using HTTP output of ORM data (encrypted of course) is a reasonable design decision, or if I should go with the direct ORMLite implementation.

Comment: 'For obvious reasons I would like to use an ORM' - please explain. Also how does the Android app communicate with your MySQL server - as you mention Tomcat as a migration?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I would like to use an ORM to abstract over the specific database implementation. As this app is for a university hospital (academic project) that _does not know it's database specifications yet_, I need to develop a versatile application. ORM also saves me from having to parse relational data directly.

Comment: As for the specifications of my Android app's communication with the MySQL server, it currently uses hibernate to connect to the host through SSL (direct connection).  Tomcat is just the only thing that comes to mind when I think "JSF"; like I said I have little experience in that area. Tomcat may not even be what I need to use. Moreover I need to know whether using HTTP output of ORM data (encrypted of course) is a reasonable design decision, or if I should go with the direct ORMLite implementation. I will edit my question thusly.

Comment: ORMlite does not support the JPA specification for single_table, joined and table per class inheritance properly. This could be a dealbreaker for you if you havnt seen the data yet. Also is there a reason you cant write the required android sqlite code yourself? Its pretty inconvenient but guaranteed to work. Use a Dao factory (taking in the entity class) if you want to keep your code clean

Comment: There is a valid chance the hospital's database doesn't use SQL. Am I necessarily wrong in assuming this? SQLite would not function in this case, correct?

Comment: If its proprietary DB then good luck getting it to work with ORMlite or hibernate which use SQL in their backend...and need the correct driver. Not sure how you plan on just offloading a non-sqlite db and having any android library reading it properly without large performance problems.

Comment: Hibernate supports NoSQL through OGM as well.

Comment: Irregardless, will using SQLite present any notable disadvantages? I'm open to anything.